# Tokenizing with different delimiters

Tags: python

say im reading a file that has a certain structure but different every line. for example, 'directory.csv' reads the following

```
November 11, Veterans’s Day
November 24, Thanksgiving
December 25, Christma
```

i want to split the lines by space, then comma so i can have the month, the day, and the holiday. i want to use re.split but i dont know how to set up the regular expression format wise. this is what i have

```
fp = open('holidays2011.csv', 'r')
import re
for item in fp :
    month, day, holiday = re.split('; |, ', item)
    print month, day, holiday
```

but when i print it says i dont have enough items to unpack. but why? im splitting at the space and the comma which gives me 3 items which i named as 3 variables

Comment: Can't the csv module handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Regular Expressions for this,

```
with open("Input.txt") as inFile:
    for item in inFile:
        datePart, holiday = item.split(", ", 1)
        month, day = datePart.split()
```

Comment: @ZachSantiago It just stops splitting after the splitting once.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting first on space is a bad idea due to the space character in the holiday name. You can use regex grouping to obtain the parts without using re.split (note the parenthesis around the parts):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """November 11, Veterans’s Day
... November 24, Thanksgiving
... December 25, Christmas"""
>>> for line in s.split('\n'):
...     month, day, holiday = re.match(r'(\w+) (\d+), (.+)', line).groups()
...     print month
...     print day
...     print holiday
...     print ''
... 
November
11
Veterans’s Day

November
24
Thanksgiving

December
25
Christmas
```

Comment: im guessing w+ d+ .+ all means something in python regular expressions?

Comment: @ZachSantiago yes, `\w` is alphabetic characters, `\d` is digits,  `.` is any character and `+` means "one or more of". You can read more about the `re` module in the docs.